# How to change a column name when the current name is NaT in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nat

I have a data frame df1 with two column Names as NaT

```
Index    NaT     Nat     2019-01-01 00:00:00
 1        A       B        1
 2        C       D        2
```

How can I change the name of the NaT columns to "Name1" and "Name2"

```
Index    Name1    Name2     2019-01-01 00:00:00
 1        A       B        1
 2        C       D        2
```

I tried the following statements:

```
df1.rename(columns = {0:'Name1', 1: 'Name2'}) #(doesn't work)

df1.columns.values[0] = 'Name1' #(doesn't work)
df1.columns.values[1] = 'Name2' #(doesn't work)
```

Comment: What type are the columns? Are they actually Timestamps, or strings?

Comment: `df.columns=df.columns.astype(str);
df.rename(columns = {'NaT':'Name1', 'Nat': 'Name2'})
`

Comment: the column names are time stamp I don't want to change the contents type just the names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign new list from columns names - first from original, next by list and next columns from 4. to last one:

```
df.columns = df.columns[:1].tolist() + ['Name1', 'Name2'] + df.columns[3:].tolist()
print (df)
   Index Name1 Name2  2019-01-01 00:00:00
0      1     A     B                    1
1      2     C     D                    2
```

Or if first column is `index` then reassing list with columns from 3. to last one:

```
df.columns = ['Name1', 'Name2'] + df.columns[2:].tolist()
print (df)
      Name1 Name2  2019-01-01 00:00:00
Index                                 
1         A     B                    1
2         C     D                    2
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having an issue where 
`df.rename(columns={"NaT": "new_column_name"}, inplace=True)` would not work because the column header NaT was actually a value (pd.NaT) and not a string.

In this case, the following code worked.
`df.rename(columns={pd.NaT: "new_column_name"}, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1):

you could just reassign directly the name of columns:

```
df1.columns = ['Name1','Name2']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_axis` like this:

```
df_out = df.set_axis(['Name1','Name2',df.columns[-1]], axis=1, inplace=False)
df_out
```

Output:

```
  Name1 Name2  2019-01-03 00:00:00
1     A     B                    1
2     C     D                    2
```

Edit to answer comment, use slicing of the column header like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape(10,-1), columns=[*'ABCDEFGHIJ'])

df = df.set_axis(['Name1']+['Name2']+df.columns[-8:].tolist(), axis=1, inplace=False)
```

Output:

```
   Name1  Name2   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J
0      0      1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1     10     11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
2     20     21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29
3     30     31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39
4     40     41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49
5     50     51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
6     60     61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69
7     70     71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79
8     80     81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89
9     90     91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99
```

Comment: this works, what if I had 50 more columns what should I use instead of df.columns[-1]

Answer (score 0):

Edit your  first code to this :

```
df1.rename(columns = {'NaT':'Name1', 'Nat': 'Name2'})
```