# rename column name `pd.NaT` in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns.
[image]

```
trxmonth    NaT 2017-07-01  2017-08-01  2017-09-01  2017-10-01  2017-11-01  2017-12-01  2018-01-01  2018-02-01  2018-03-01  ... 2021-12-01  2022-01-01  2022-02-01  2022-03-01  2022-04-01  2022-05-01  2022-06-01  2022-07-01  2022-08-01
```

I use `reset_index` for remove value as an index and add into columns and it works fine but column name is `Nat`. I try to change `Nat-> customer_name` but it doesn't change.

I use this code:
**CODE:**

```
df.rename(columns={pd.NaT: "customer_name"})
```

but it can effect others column too.
[image]

Simply I want to change `NaT to customer_name`. I also use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55424411/how-to-change-a-column-name-when-the-current-name-is-nat-in-pandas) but it cannot help me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give something reproducible? When I try it on my dummy dataset, it works fine

Comment: okay i will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
c = pd.DatetimeIndex([ 'NaT', '2017-07-01', '2017-08-01', '2017-09-01', '2017-10-01', '2017-11-01', '2017-12-01', 
                      '2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01'],
                       dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='trxmonth', freq=None)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=c, index=[0])
```

First convert columns names to strings `YYYY-MM-DD` for avoid added `00:00:00` times if mixed columns names - datetimes and string `customer_name`:

```
#default datetimes has 00:00:00 times
print (df.columns.tolist())
[NaT, Timestamp('2017-07-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-08-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-09-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2017-10-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-11-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-12-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-02-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2018-03-01 00:00:00')]
```

---

```
df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df = df.rename(columns={np.nan: "customer_name"})
print (df)
trxmonth customer_name 2017-07-01 2017-08-01 2017-09-01 2017-10-01 2017-11-01  \
0                  NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   

trxmonth 2017-12-01 2018-01-01 2018-02-01 2018-03-01  
0               NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Or convert values to dates:

```
df.columns = df.columns.date
df = df.rename(columns={pd.NaT: "customer_name"})
print (df)
  customer_name 2017-07-01 2017-08-01 2017-09-01 2017-10-01 2017-11-01  \
0           NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN   

  2017-12-01 2018-01-01 2018-02-01 2018-03-01  
0        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4]], columns=[pd.NaT, '2017-07-01', '2017-08-01', '2017-09-01'])
df.rename(columns={pd.NaT: "customer_name"})
```

Output:

```
   customer_name  2017-07-01  2017-08-01  2017-09-01
0              1           2           3           4
```

Comment: I run your code snippets `Nat` data type is int64 but my data type is `object`

Comment: When I change `[1,2,3,4]` into `['1', '2', '3', '4']` it still works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to change column header by index, such as `df.columns.values[n]`, additionally to get index position dynamically you can try to run loop and check if its NaT or not.

As your column names types are datetime, try to put condition where you will compare the type.

Code:

```
df.columns.values[[i for i,d in enumerate(df.columns) if type(d)==type(pd.NaT)]] = 'customer_name'
df.columns
```

Ouput:

```
Index([' ', 2015-02-17 16:53:25, 'customer_name'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: it can shows me an error `ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "customer_name" at position 0`

Comment: Hi @Mehmaam you are receiving that error because your column name type is datetime. Please check updated code.

Answer (score 0):

try recreating the columns as follows, first convert to string and then  get the column names excluding NaT, add ['customer_name'] in the place you want it.

df.columns = ['customer_name'] + df.columns.astype(str).tolist()[1:]

Comment: It shows me an error `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "DatetimeArray") to list`

Comment: what do you get when you type df.columns[:10]?

Comment: DatetimeIndex([       'NaT', '2017-07-01', '2017-08-01', '2017-09-01',
               '2017-10-01', '2017-11-01', '2017-12-01', '2018-01-01',
               '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='trxmonth', freq=None)

Comment: you can try this... \ndf.columns = ['customer_name'] + df.columns.astype(str).to_list()[1:]